# Laravel email contact form 7

Tags: laravel, email

I'm developing a small script locally, which allows users to send an email from the post posted by another user. A simple contact form that then sends an email from user to user.

I have configured my .env with the corresponding Mailtrap sample data.

My problem is that every email sent is sent to Mailtrap and not to the user's email.

```
public function html_email(Request $request) 
    {
        
        $request->validate([
            'message_to' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);

        $data = array('name' => Auth::user()->name);
        
        Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) {
            $message
                ->to(request('email_to'))
                ->subject('Someone is interested in your ad!');
            
            $message->from(Auth::user()->email, Auth::user()->name);
        });
        
        return back()
            ->with('success', __('app.email_successfully_sent'));
        
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: mailtrap is used to test email, not to send real mail (soo, you have to use a real mail client, like GMAIL, if you want to send real email)

Comment: It's a fake SMTP server which you can simulate emails before sending to real customers.

Comment: Ok, but setting a real email in .env when in a post a user has to contact another user, where is the email addressed? To the email set by default to .env? I want it to be sent to the email address of the user who posted the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but setting a real email in .env when in a post a user has to contact another user, where is the email addressed? To the email set by default to .env? I want it to be sent to the email address of the user who posted the post.